# Is it possible to use Flexslider and Fancybox in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, instantiation, flexslider

I have an issue once I plug in scripts, css, jquery for Fancybox, my flexslider script does not work. I receive this error:

```
JavaScript Error: TypeError: $(".flexslider").flexslider is not a function.
```

When I remove the fancybox scripts, my flexslider works. Is it possible to use both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have them both working on one of my sites:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(); 
    $('.flexslider').flexslider()
;});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use them both. may you tried to use them before they are downloaded.

According API of them you need to add these plugins in this way

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'm such a dummy when it comes to using scripts! Thanks.